# Creating pre-assembled HTML elements with variables in PHP (read for better explanation)

Tags: php, html, function, variables

Long-time listener, first-time poster.

I'm creating basic websites for clients, and I'm trying to learn PHP by doing so. I've done lots of research for certain things on sites like PHP.net, w3schools, and Stack Overflow. I can't find how to do this specific thing though because my Google-fu and PHP-fu are not strong.

One of the websites I'm working on is for a restaurant, and the first page has a blog-post-looking thing.

I want to make it so that I can refer to a pre-assembled piece of HTML and pass variables to it (like post heading and post content).

The blog posts are in a 3x3 table with graphics:

```
<table class="postBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td class="topLeft"></td>
    <td class="topCenter"><span class="postHeader">Welcome!</span></td>
    <td class="topRight"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="middleLeft"></td>
    <td class="contentCenter"><p class="postBody">CONTENT CONTENT</p></td>
    <td class="middleRight"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bottomLeft"></td>
    <td class="bottomCenter"></td>
    <td class="bottomRight"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm sure this is a very simple basic thing, but I'm just now stepping into PHP and I love the Stack Overflow community! Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want a view. Look up MVC and grab a framework, even minimal one.

Comment: Have a look at www.smarty.net

Comment: You should really use a framework (or a templating engine at the very least), disregard the answers below, especially the ones that tells you to use wix.com or Dreamweawer.

Comment: I will research frameworks for the next website I build, but for now, I pieced together a solution involving includes and functions. I'm sure that's not the best way to go about it, but it's what I'm comfortable with now, especially since this website needs put together in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

In a .php file you can do:

```
<?php
 $content = 'Hello World!';
?>

....
<p class="postBody"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
....
```

To output the html with php-variables replaced.